# Understanding the definition of asymptotic normality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, definition, time-series

Consider the following definition.

> A sequence of random variables ${(X_n)}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is called
>   asymptotically normally distributed if there exist sequences $\mu_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma_n: 0 < \sigma_n < \infty$ such that
>
> $$ \frac{1}{\sigma_n}(X_n - \mu_n) \overset{d}{\rightarrow}
> \mathscr{N}(0,1). $$ In this case one writes $X_n \sim AN(0,1)$.

I was wondering whether the above implies that there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that all the random variables $X_n$ for $n > n_0$ will be normally distributed with parameters $(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$?

Comment: Well, no, the same way that for sequences having $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$ does not imply  the existence of some $N$ such that $a_n = 0$ for every $n\geq N$. In your case, consider the "usual" Central Limit Theorem for easy counterexamples.

Comment: Shouldn't the notation be $X_n \sim AN(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$? In any case, no. As Clement C says, the central limit theorem provides a large class of examples. Here's another: if $X_n$ denotes the number of cycles of a random permutation, then it turns out that we have $X_n \sim AN(\log n, \log n)$, but all of these random variables are discrete and so none of them are normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reproducing and expanding my comment above:*

Well, **no**, the same way that for sequences having $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a$ does not imply the existence of some $N$ such that $a_n=a$ for every $n\geq N$. In your case, consider the "usual" [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) for easy counterexamples.

For instance, consider $(Y_n)_n$ to be a sequence of i.i.d. Rademacher random variables (uniform on $\{-1,1\}$). Then $X_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=}  \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$ defines a sequence of random variables, and by the CLT we have
$$
 \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
so (taking $\sigma_n=\sqrt{n}$ and $\mu_n=0$ for all $n$) $(X_n)_n$ is asymptotically normally distributed. However, for every $n\geq 1$ we have that  $X_n$ is discrete, so definitely not normally distributed (actually at statistical distance $1$ from Gaussian).